# Podman & podman-compose: add local directory as a volume

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I'm trying to set up a Wordpress development environment using Podman and [podman-compose](https://github.com/containers/podman-compose).

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  wordpress:

services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    image: wordpress:php8.1-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
    environment:  
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

I have other services, such as Nginx and MariaDB, but for simplicity's sake I'll use only wordpress in this example.

Problem is that I'm not able to add ./wordpress directory as a volume. If I do this with `docker-compose` it works but with `podman-compose`I get `no such file or directory` error message. Same thing happens when I try to start the container directly with `podman run` command.

If I replace the local directory with named volume, then it works:

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  wordpress:

volumes:
  wordpress:

services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    image: wordpress:php8.1-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
    environment:  
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

However, this is not a working solution in my use case. I want to create a wordpress project template that I can clone into my computer, fire up the containers, install Wordpress and start editing the files in local directory.

Is there a way of achieving this behavior using Podman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the `:delegated` and use following template:

```
- ./wordpress:/var/www/html:rw,z
```

so the whole compose file would be:

```
version: "4"
services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    image: wordpress:php8.1-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:rw,z
    environment:  
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress
networks:
  wordpress:
volumes:
  wordpress:
```